# How to get a particular preceding value of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want a new column for each record which will have the time corresponding to a particular previous value.

**Input:**

| id | value | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1-1-2019 10:00 AM |
| 1 | 2 | 1-1-2019 10:15 AM |
| 1 | 2 | 1-1-2019 10:30 AM |
| 1 | 3 | 1-1-2019 10:45 AM |
| 2 | 2 | 1-1-2019 11:00 AM |
| 2 | 5 | 1-1-2019 11:15 AM |
| 2 | 6 | 1-1-2019 11:30 AM |

**Output:** time2 corresponds to a particular previous value. (EX. value=2)

| id | value | datetime | datetime2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1-1-2019 10:00 AM | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 1-1-2019 10:15 AM | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 1-1-2019 10:30 AM | 1-1-2019 10:15 AM |
| 1 | 3 | 1-1-2019 10:45 AM | 1-1-2019 10:30 AM |
| 2 | 2 | 1-1-2019 11:00 AM | NULL |
| 2 | 5 | 1-1-2019 11:15 AM | 1-1-2019 11:00 AM |
| 2 | 6 | 1-1-2019 11:30 AM | 1-1-2019 11:00 AM |

Points:

1. I am using SQL Server (SSMS). I tried lag but don't know how to pick the last particular value
2. The data is partitioned by id and ordered by time
3. The previous criteria is - I will look for a particular value (as in this example I am looking for value 2). If value 2 is present previously in the partition then it will return its corresponding time otherwise NULL

*updated the time with real values

Initially I thought of lag function but the problem is lag function can take only below 3 arguments -

First argument is column name - But here I am searching for a particular value in value column and returning the time column, so not really sure which column to pass as the first parameter

Second argument is Offset - The lag function uses this argument forgo behind the number of rows. But in this scenario it is not fixed how forgo behind the value=2 is.

Third argument is Default - For example, we specified offset value 3 for the first row. A lag function cannot go three rows behind. It displays the default value if specified. If we do not specify any value for this, the lag function displays NULL in the output for out of range values

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your DB vendor and DB version.
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer will probably be product specific.

Comment: Look into `LAG`.

Comment: I am using sql server (SSMS). I tried lag but dont know how to pick the last particular value.

Comment: I want the corresponding time value for a particular last occuring element in a partition(For ex. In the above case I am taking the time for last occuring 2)

Comment: Your data set is missing the criteria by which you define *previous*; There is no inherent ordering to rows in a table unless you provide it, which you have not specified - is it id and value combined?.

Comment: @Stu, The data is partitioned by id and ordered by time

Comment: The previous criteria is - I will look for a particular value(as in this example I am looking for value 2). If value 2 is present previously in the partition then it will return its corresponding time otherwise 0

Comment: Show us your attempt(s) with lag, explain why they didn't work.

Comment: Are your `time` values really letters of the alphabet? I know a minimal example is encouraged. but thats too minimal. If they should be time values then please show time values.

Comment: @DaleK Updated to real time values.

Comment: Well you've used datetime values not just time values - is that what you are storing? And 0 isn't a valid datetime value.

Comment: @ysth select version(); returns --> Microsoft Azure SQL datawarehouse - 10.0.13582

Comment: @DaleK I have updated them to NULL, since there is no previous record which has value=2 for them.

Comment: Now if you'll just show us your non-working lag attempt you'll have a complete question. Although if you want to make it really easy to answer, add your input data as DDL+DML to save us having to type it in.

Comment: @DaleK mentioned the reason why I cant use the lag function. If there is something I missed or if I misunderstood the lag function, please let me know, I will check.

Comment: Use lag to lag both columns initially, then compare the lagged value with 2 and if its 2 show the lagged time value using a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a running, conditional `MAX` to get the latest `datetime` value when `value = 2`.**

You can exclude the current row by using `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.value,
  t.datetime,
  datetime2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.value = 2 THEN t.datetime END)
       OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.datetime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM YourTable t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83071a/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using an internal select you can combine the current row with the previous values with the specifications you want.

Check condition : `where t2.id = t1.id and t2.value = 2 and t1.datetime > t2.datetime`

```
select *,(select max(datetime) from YourTable t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.value = 2 and t1.datetime > t2.datetime)
from YourTable t1
```

Comment: Some explanation of how your answer works would greatly approve this answer. The OP should be able to learn from this, not just copy/past and be glad it works.

Comment: I could hardly understand the question so I could find the answer. But I can hardly enter the explanation.